# Convert SQL String Column which is in JSON format into Variables

Tags: sql, json, string

I have a SQL column of type String but that has content in JSON format as follows:

```
[{"name": "abc", "val": 0.90}, {"name": "def", "val": 0.22}, {"name": "ghi", "probability": 0.0.3}]
```

I would like to process this SQL column data in a Stored Procedure Row by Row and would like to stored these values into variable like name1, val1, name2, val2, name3 and val3.
How can I stored these values into variables?

```
DECLARE @sample varchar(500) = '[{"name": "abc", "val": 0.90}, {"name": "def", "val": 0.22}, {"name": "ghi", "probability": 0.0.3}]'

Select substring(@sample,2, len(@sample)-2)
```

Comment: Which RDMBS / database engine are you using?  Depending on which platform you are working with there may be native functions that can parse JSON to return rows/columns that you can select from (as if the data was in a tabular form)

Comment: tag your database as well